#  How to use Facebook FBML instead of iframe in my app?

Tags: facebook, fbml, sandbox, facebook-iframe

I want to use FBML instead iframe in facebook but if I enable FBML then I must to enable sandbox before

If I enable sandbox then my application http://apps.facebook.com/uologic becomes offline and give error "Requested Page Not Found"

How to use Facebook FBML instead of iframe? It's working with iframe but I don't want iframe.

Answer (score 1):

It's not optional, you simply **can't**! - [reference](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/)

> **No new FBML apps**  We will stop allowing new FBML apps, but will
>   continue to support existing FBML tabs
>   and apps. Instead, we recommend using
>   iframes.